# Description for second item is not displaying completely as like the first item in CQWP when using itemstyles

Tags: content-query-web-part, item-styles

Description for second item is not displaying completely as like the first item in CQWP when using itemstyles. The below custom itemstyle i have used.

```
            <div class="Corpdescriptionstyle" style="height:200px;">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Description, 0, 690)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">..more</a></div>

            </td>               
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a substring for 690 characteres max to display

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@Description, 0, 690)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Are you sure that your description is less than 690 chars?

If it is a case check the height of you container: you have set this to 200px. Try to remove this height to check if it is the case.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Description is less than 690 characters, for the first item,only the first line is displaying. And for the second item, it displaying more than 5 lines

Comment: Try to read this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265334/how-to-access-variable-in-cdata-from-xslt, maybe it helps